# Problem with categorization in pandas/OrdinalEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoder, ordinal

I'm having some problems categorizing a column using pandas and OrdinalEncoder.
What I have to do is basically, convert a column to be categorical (so that I can use OrdinalEncoder after) but everything I try either doesn't work or returns NaN.

What I tried is the following:

`df['Education']` is a column with all the data of the degrees obtained by the sample.

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype
ordcat = CategoricalDtype(categories = ['Preschool', '1st-4th', '5th-6th', '7th-8th', '9th', '10th', '11th', '12th', 'HS-grad',
 'Prof-school', 'Assoc-acdm', 'Assoc-voc', 'Some-college', 'Bachelors', 'Masters',
 'Doctorate'], ordered = True)
df['Education'] = df['Education'].astype(ordcat)
print(df['Education'])
```

The output is the following:

```
    category
0        NaN
1        NaN
2        NaN
3        NaN
4        NaN
        ... 
32556    NaN
32557    NaN
32558    NaN
32559    NaN
32560    NaN
```

Which isn't what I need.
I also tried doing something different but didn't really give me any result other than errors about `Series being mutable` or `NaN`s again.

It's been like 4 days and I can't figure things out, do you have any idea of what I'm missing?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Edit_0**: The database I'm using is the following: [UCI Machine Learning repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data) (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/adult/adult.data) which I alredy stripped and put `np.nan` in place of `?`

Comment: your code is not reproduisible, add your intial dataframe

Comment: The post have been edited

Answer (score 0):

How do you declare `df`? Maybe you can try to create an empty dataframe series first and name it as `Education`. Then, execute the `df['Education'] = df['Education'].astype(ordcat)`.

Comment: `df` was declared with:

`pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
concatenated = pd.concat(replaced, axis = 1)
df = concatenated.fillna(np.NaN)`

where `replaced` are the stripped columns and `concatenated` is the concatenated dataframe

Comment: In `concatenated = pd.concat(replaced, axis = 1)`, which dataframes do you concatenate? There is only one in `concat` function which is `replaced`. Maybe your results are due to filling `na`'s with `np.NaN`. Try create an empty dataframe first. Then, concatenate with the other dataframe.

Comment: `concatenated` is the concatenation of replaced which is a series of columns (namely each column present in the dataframe to which I applied the `replace` method to remove the `?`).

Luckily I fixed all the mess described above by redoing everything from scratch and it kinda works now!
Thanks again for your contribution